# Dired: manual files sorting for specific directories

Tags: dired, customize, sorting

I have a directory with many folder. When I open it in dired I see this:

```
bundles
ckeditor
companies
contries
failitators
induction
jquery_update
lwt_shared
members
messages
offices
...
```

I often work upon files from specific directory and my idea was to create a file with sorting order. And make the folder I need now to float to the top. All the other dirs should be sorted by name.

For example, I am working upon members and offices dirs:

```
members
offices
bundles
ckeditor
companies
...
```

And our sorting file located in parent dir should be something like this:

```
members
offices
```

Then Emacs will know, that members and offices must be put at the top. Is it possible to implement it? I read http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredSorting, and it says, that sorting can be changed by customizing per-directory local variables.

But how should I write this file?

Comment: The kind of sorting the manual talks about relates to the flags of UNIX `ls` command, this, unfortunately, isn't the kind of sorting you want to achieve. However, you could approach this problem differently: you could write a file (just save the dired buffer into file) with a `# -*- mode: dired -*-` comment, and change the order of directories in that file. This way once you load it, you will have the order you saved it in + the dired functionality.